# custom scientific format in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

In microsoft excel, I want to use the scientific format for a number. However the built-in format will the number with one digit in the left of the point.

For example, it shows `2000000` as `2.0E+6`. However I want this `20.0E+5`, or `0.2E+7`.

How it is possible to change the number format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the number format to the Custom category, and enter `00.0E+0`. You can change the `00.0` before the decimal point in order to customize the scientific format. For example, this number format would show `20.0E+5`, but if you change it to `0.0E+0`, it will show as `2.0E+6`.

Comment: And is there a way to change the threshold of switching to scientific?